# Pre-Linking Pages in HTML Before Uploading

Tags: html, web-hosting, dreamweaver

I am currently creating a website with over 700 pages and I would like to be able to link them together before I upload the files to my host server if possible. Is there a good way to link pages together pre-upload without  for sure knowing what the final URLs are going to be?

I am working in and plan to upload/manage my website files through Dreamweaver.

I have seen the prompt in Dreamweaver to update links before. If I link the file paths now, will it update to the URLs when the site is uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use root-relative links. do some searching on that. as long as you don't change your file structure you will be good where your site is run.

instead of using absolute links such as `http://www.website.com/folder1/page1`

you would use `/folder1/page1`

as long as your root was where you started the paths from you can start with "/" as above.

there are some instances where you would do a relative link from a certain folder to another one `../folder1/page1` this is not something i would recommend here.

good luck and comment on this if you have more questions.